# How to sessionize / group the events in Akka Streams?

Tags: akka-stream, reactive-streams, akka-kafka

The requirement is that I want to write an Akka streaming application that listens to continuous events from Kafka, then sessionizes the event data in a time frame, based on some id value embedded inside each event.

For example, let's say that my time frame window is two minutes, and in the first two minutes I get the four events below:

Input:

```
{"message-domain":"1234","id":1,"aaa":"bbb"}
{"message-domain":"1234","id":2,"aaa":"bbb"}
{"message-domain":"5678","id":4,"aaa":"bbb"}
{"message-domain":"1234","id":3,"aaa":"bbb"}
```

Then in the output, after grouping/sessionizing these events, I will have only two events based on their message-domain value.

Output:

```
{"message-domain":"1234",messsages:[{"id":1,"aaa":"bbb"},{"id":2,"aaa":"bbb"},{"id":4,"aaa":"bbb"}]}
{"message-domain":"5678",messsages:[{"id":3,"aaa":"bbb"}]}
```

And I want this to happen in real time. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

To group the events within a time window you can use [`Flow.groupedWithin`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/scaladsl/Flow.html#groupedWithin(n:Int,d:scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration):FlowOps.this.Repr[scala.collection.immutable.Seq[Out]]):

```
val maxCount : Int = Int.MaxValue

val timeWindow = FiniteDuration(2L, TimeUnit.MINUTES)

val timeWindowFlow : Flow[String, Seq[String]] =
  Flow[String] groupedWithin (maxCount, timeWindow)
```

Comment: How do you group the events based on a particular id here  ? so events having same message-domain value will end up as a single event after grouping.

Comment: @dks551 That part of your question is much more involved.  It requires significant string manipulation to get the format that you are looking for.  Could it instead return a dict with key `1234` and a value of `Seq[String]` where the values in the sequence are the strings?  Or, convert each string into a case class?